# Find the line in a file starting with specific word

Tags: search, find, tcl

I would like to get the line number in my file **starting** with the specific word. For the below example I would only like to get number 5, if I am searching for bind.

```
module checker_m;
// bind
`include "assertions.v"
endmodule
bind top checker_m checker_inst ();
```

If you can guys suggest me a Tcl solution, that would be the best - I am working in a tool with the **Tcl** interpreter. Any Linux based command I can call with "exec" is the option.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `gets`:

```
set word bind
set n 0
set f [open file]
while {[gets $f line] >= 0} {
    incr n
    if {[string match $word* $line]} {
        puts "Line $n"
    }
}
close $f
```

A similar solution using the `fileutil` package.

```
package require fileutil

set word bind
set n 0
::fileutil::foreachLine line file {
    incr n
    if {[string match $word* $line]} {
        puts "Line $n"
    }
}
```

A one-liner solution:

```
lindex [split [lindex [::fileutil::grep ^$word\\M file] 0] :] 1
```

Documentation:
[>= (operator)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm),
[close](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/close.htm),
[fileutil (package)](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.html),
[gets](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/gets.htm),
[if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm),
[incr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/incr.htm),
[lindex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm),
[open](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm),
[package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm),
[puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm),
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm),
[while](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/while.htm),
[Syntax of Tcl regular expressions](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm)

*Syntax of Tcl string matching:*

- `*` matches a sequence of zero or more characters
- `?` matches a single character
- `[chars]` matches a single character in the set given by *chars* (^ does *not* negate; a range can be given as *a-z*)
- `\x` matches the character *x*, even if that character is special (one of `*?[]\`)

Answer (score 1):

```
set lineno [exec grep -n {^bind\>} $filename | cut -d: -f1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the filename is held in the variable fnm and that the list of words you want to search for is in the variable candidates, something like this should work:

```
# Read in all the input data

set fil [open $fnm]
set data [read $fil]
close $fnm

# Check each input line to see whether if the first word appears in the
# candidate list

set lineNo 0
foreach line [split $data \n] {
    incr lineNo
    set words [split $line " "]
    set firstWord [lindex $words 0]
    if {[lsearch $candidates $firstWord] >= 0} {
        puts stdout "Line $lineNo starts with $firstWord"
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: I haven't actually tested this so it may well contain some silly errors, but I believe it illustrates the principles correctly. If your input file is *very* large, you might be better reading it a line at a time using `gets` and testing the lines as you read them, but I certainly couldn't write that (almost) correctly first time out.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks! That worked! What would you consider as a large file? My file is less than 2k lines.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. The "problem" with my solution using `read` is that you have to store the whole file in the memory space of your process. With a modern computer system, I wouldn't worry until it got to a megabyte or more; this should allow you to handle a file of several tens of thousand lines, so you 2000-odd line file shouldn't be a problem.